# How do I group by time in R and plot with ggplot? Can this be done within ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm analysing app data using R and I find myself having to group by time a lot so I can plot it in ggplot, however this doesn't seem easy to do.

my data looks like:

```
user_id | session_id | timestamp | time_seconds
 001    |   123      | 2014-01-01|    251
 002    |   845      | 2014-01-01|    514
 003    |   741      | 2014-01-02|    141
 003    |   477      | 2014-01-03|    221
 004    |   121      | 2014-01-03|    120
 005    |   921      | 2014-01-04|    60
...
```

The time_stamp column is formatted with `as.Date()` so it should be recognised as a date by R.

I need to plot line graphs showing no. of sessions over time in ggplot. Is there a simple way to do this within the ggplot code? for example:

```
ggplot(df, aes(timestamp,count(session_id)))+
  geom_line()
```

I want to do a count of sessions per date, the above code doesn't work, just an example to show what I'm after.

What I'd also like to do is then summarise by month. I'd also like to look into specific months and would like to subset the data. Can this be done from that line of code? `xlim` isn't what I'm after as that just "shortens" the axis.

I've tried using the `aggregate` function but with mixed results, not really what I've been after.

Thanks.

Comment: `help("stat_summary")`

Comment: Do you want to plot the result of `aggregate(session_id ~ timestamp, df, length)`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas yes I would like to plot that.

Comment: Then save it `res <- aggregate(etc)` and use `res` in the posted `ggplot` command, I have just done that.

Comment: Thanks, whilst it works, it seems like a slightly long way of grouping data, I was wondering whether there was a way of doing this in the `ggplot(...)` line of code. I'm going to be summarising a lot of data so wondering if I have to keep creating a lot of objects as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_by` and `summarize` from the `dplyr`-package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%  
  group_by(timestamp) %>% 
  summarise(session_count = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(timestamp, session_count)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

For summarizing the data by month you can do:

```
df %>%  
  mutate(month_timestamp = format(timestamp, "%b %Y")) %>% 
  group_by(month_timestamp) %>% 
  summarise(session_count = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(month_timestamp, session_count)) + 
  geom_line()
```

The plot here doesn't show something because there's only one month in your data.

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(user_id = c("001", "002", "003", "003", "004", "005"), 
                     session_id = c("123", "845", "741", "477", "121", "921"), 
                     timestamp = structure(c(16071, 16071, 16072, 16073, 16073, 16074), 
                                           class = "Date"), 
                     time_seconds = c(251, 514, 141, 221, 120, 60)), 
                .Names = c("user_id", "session_id", "timestamp", "time_seconds"), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm inputting this code (changed DF and col names to fit my data): `events %>%  
  mutate(month_timestamp = format(event_timestamp, "%b %Y")) %>% 
  group_by(month_timestamp) %>% 
  summarise(session_count = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(month_timestamp, session_count)) + 
  geom_line()` but I'm getting this message: `geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?` along with a blank graph.

Comment: Check your output of `events %>% mutate(month_timestamp = format(event_timestamp, "%b %Y")) %>% group_by(month_timestamp) %>% summarise(session_count = n())`. In the data you provided, there is only one month so `geom_path` doesn't work. If you use `geom_point` instead it should plot one point.

Comment: You can also try adding `group = 1` to `aes()` and it should work @jceg316

Comment: sorry, just noticed something about this. The X axis is showing months in alphabetical order as opposed to time order.

Comment: Replace `"%b %Y"` with `"%Y %m"` for example (as in @erocoar solution) or convert `month_timestamp` to a `factor` and specify the ordering of the levels, or use `scale_x_discrete` to set the order of the labels (with (`breaks =`).

Answer (score 0):

Might also be convenient to do with lubridate, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(timestamp = rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2014/01/01"), as.Date("2014/12/24"), "day"), each = 2),
                  sessions = 1)

dat %>% 
  mutate(month = format(timestamp, "%Y-%m")) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  summarise(sum_session = sum(sessions)) %>% 
  ggplot(data = e, aes(x = month, y = sum_session, group = 1)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however i'm inputting this: `events %>% 
  mutate(month = format(event_timestamp, "%Y-%m")) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  summarise(sum_session = sum(user_session_id)) %>% 
  ggplot(data = e, aes(x = month, y = sum_session, group = 1)) + geom_line()` and getting back this error: `Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: <U+0091>sum<U+0092> not meaningful for factors.`

Comment: That is likely because `session_id` is not a vector of 1s as in my example. Adding `sum_session = n()` should fix that